# Cross-validation on small dataset

Tags: regression, cross-validation, linear

I have a very small dataset (n=42) and use simple bivariate linear regression to predict the target variable. As i understood from several posts on this webpage, in case of small datasets one should skip the train-split method and directly use the cross-validation, specifically LOOCV.

What i do not quite understand is how one gets model coefficient and intercept of the best fit? I am using the following script:

```
   loocv = model_selection.LeaveOneOut()
   lm=LinearRegression()
   predictions = cross_val_predict(lm, x, y, cv=loocv.get_n_splits(x))
   cross_val_score(lm,x,y,cv=loocv.get_n_splits(x)
```

Comment: CV is done for predictions, at the end you would build your model on the whole data and those are your coefficients.

Comment: Would you please add the data to the question, or post a link to the data?

Answer (score 0):

Cross validation will give you an out-of-sample estimation for your prediction performance. For example you could use it to report your out of sample R2.

As pointed out by @user2974951 the coefficients are estimated on your complete dataset. [I would recommend you use statsmodels for this task, which will give you a nice OLS summary](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html).

**Please note that [you will have to check your ols model for statistical regression assumptions](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/linear-regression-using-spss-statistics.php)**, because you want to use it for explanation (i.e. study coefficients). You need to do this no matter what R2 you achieved.

Please also note that with statsmodels [you need to add the intercept manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20701559/2672299).